# Search Performance in case of special refinements

Tags: php, search, lucene, sphinx

I have a search refinement logic in way that more the number of search-parameters /search-cluster used by a user worsen the speed as still all cluster need to be displayed and for each selected search-parameters/cluster , a separate search needs to be performed.

For eg:
if a user has specified city=1, price=1 and producttype=1 in the search, then sill all the clusters would be shown (including the clusters for city, price, producttype) and a separate search would be performed for each selected search parameter's cluster.In this case, for showing the clusters for city, the where condition in the query would include producttype=1 and price-1, for showing the clusters for price, the where condition would include city=1 and producttype=1, and so on.

Also i have additional 10 clusters for whom city=1 and producttype=1 abd price=1 will be performed.

Question:
I m using sphinx & php and in sphinx i need to fire multiple queries.
How should i optimize it ? (i m using mutiqueries.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Solr
it has inbuilt functionality for this